# shouldChangeCharactersInRange not work in ios7-64bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, 64-bit

I use this method to replace and check real time input in uitextfield, but this not work on ios 7 - 64 bit

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == textInput) {

        NSString * text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@"?"];
        [textField setText:text];
        return NO;
    }
return YES;
}
```

This textField i check and only input number, but in ios7-64bit it only input max 4 numbers.

Have any solution for this?

Comment: How do you declare this **textInput**

Answer (score 0):

`shouldChangeCharactersInRange` This should be working as well as IOS7 . No Changes for the delegates of `UITextField` .

**Check these :**
Ensure about the `delegate set to the UITextField`.

```
self.textInput.delegate = self;
```

And Are you sure about the Condition of `if (textField == textInput)`

> This Code working fine for me. :

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString * text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@"?"];
    [textField setText:text];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: But in ios7-64bit (device: iphone5s). this work not correctly. when i input number max is 4 but i want input more